# How to receive notification that android has killed my application?

Tags: android

I want to know how can we detect that operating system has killed my app due to low memory?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have all your activity extend a base activity.
Override the base activity onDestroy() to throwa notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you show the native source code, show this points.

1.] Detect "Not enough memory" situation
   (function tryMalloc in /dalvik/vm/alloc/heap.c)
2.] ActivityManager kill the process. 
    (method requestFinishActivityLocked in ActivityStack.java)
3.] report process is died.
    (method appDiedLocked in ActivityManagerService.java)